# React.js - passing functions between components using Context API - not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a function between two components but even though I do not have any errors, the function that I am passing wont show or to be precise it is not working. I have two files and one of them is creating a context while the other is using it (obviously). Now, they are not shown in App.js (which is rendered in index.js, usual stuff) they are in the seperate folder. I am using React Router to show one the pages (News.js).

Here are the files:

NewsContext.js

```
import React, { useContext, createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const newsK = React.createContext();

export const NewsContext = (props) => {

  const working = () => {
    console.log("it is working");
  };

  return <newsK.Provider value={working}>{props.children}</newsK.Provider>;
};

export default NewsContext;
```

News.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { newsK } from "./NewsContext";
import { NewsContext } from "./NewsContext";


const News = () => {
  const data = useContext(newsK);
  return (
    <NewsContext>
      <div>
        <button onClick={data}></button>
      </div>
    </NewsContext>
  );
};

export default News;
```

When i pressed the button, it wont do anything. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use context outside the `NewsContext` component

The solution for this will be to create a component that will call useContext inside `NewsContext`.

I.e.

```
const WrappedButton = () => {
  const data = useContext(newsK)

  return <button onClick={data} />
}
```

And then put it inside the NewsContext:

```
<NewsContext>
  <div>
    <WrappedButton />
  </div>
</NewsContext>
```